# Open source Graph library

Tags: c#, c++, graphics, charts

I am looking for any open source/free graph(charting) library in C/C++ or C#.  Just like free JfreeChart in java. 
Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of gnuplot... It's open-source and very versatile.

Comment: Put it's mainly a program, not a library. I've seen one program that automated gnuplot and that was a pretty horrible user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14422) for .Net.
Samples are also [available](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart).

Comment: is it free? @Saurabh01 has asked for 'open source/free graph(charting) library in C/C++ or C#'

Comment: AFAIK, it's not open source software. However, you can use it and distribute it free of charge (on windows platforms).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

[DynamicDataDisplay](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) for C# is free and a quite efficient way of charting data. It supports quick pans and zooms.